# Google Analytics tracking for tab rleated mvc application

Tags: google-analytics

I have MVC application it contains only one page with multiple tabs. I am loading the data using ajax call. I want to include GA to track the the tabs tat are navigated. I am using the GA code in my layout page.

I know i have to call _gaq.push method to track the page  on each of my tab. but my question is there any way to do it on commmon place so that I dont want to repeat the code in all tabs (as I have 15-16 tabs)

Regards,
Karthik G

Answer (score 0):

I would give the tab links a class, then use jQuery's .on to listen for clicks to trigger the GA pageviews.

Something like this...

```
    $('.tabclass').on('click', function(){
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/' + this.text])});
```